# How to format a date in AngularJS (Datefilter)

Tags: angularjs, date, angularjs-scope, angular-filters, ng-bind

I need to format a date with the AngularJS date-filter. Unformatted the date looks like this:

```
2017-03-02T00:00:00.000Z
```

**What I want to achieve:**

```
03/02/2017
```

I use the date-filter like this:

```
<p data-ng-bind="selectedEvent.start" | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'>{{selectedEvent.start}}</p>
```

And this is what I get:

```
Thu Mar 02 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0000
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you read this? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: I did.. Still getting the wrong format..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right and wrong.

```
<p data-ng-bind="selectedEvent.start | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'"></p>
```

You were binding the date, but then had the filtering outside the quote. Then you had the double braces inside the

too, which was a duplicate.

Comment: Oh.. Ok, I fixed the error but I still get this unwanted format: Wed Mar 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0000

Answer (score 1):

You are closing your model value before adding the filter.
Instead of writing

```
<p data-ng-bind="selectedEvent.start" | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'>{{selectedEvent.start}}</p>
```

Write this

```
<p data-ng-bind="selectedEvent.start | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'"></p>
```

And you dont need {{}} afterwards, since you are binding the value already.

Comment: Oh.. Ok, I fixed the error but I still get this unwanted format: Wed Mar 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0000

Comment: @Codehan Go through the link https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date and you can find any format you want.

Comment: @Shiva nope, i always get the wrong format even if I use the right filter..